# `go run hello.go` cannot find the "hello.go" file

Tags: go

I tried to run the program in command prompt #Go lang- But when i type run "go run hello.go" command i am gettin

> CreateFile hello.go:The system cannot find the file specified

Please help to to compile and run the above marked program, Thanks in advance

Comment: Please consider not posting links to screenshots! While they contain text, this text is not indexed by the Internet search engines. The Windows console supports copying and pasting: with default settings, the right mouse button can be used to enter selection mode, and when you're done with selecting, hit the Enter key to copy the selected text to the clipboard. You can then paste it to your question (and then format it as code).

Comment: need more info to help properly

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the output of running the `dir` command
earlier up in your shell session, there is indeed no file named "hello.go"
in the `C:\GOCODE\testproject` directory.

When you execute the

```
go run hello.go
```

command, the `go` tool tries to find the file named "hello.go" in the current
directory (because the name of that file is relative, so it's being
searched in current working directory).  There's no such file,
and that's what `go run` tells you.

---

Unfortunately, from the outlook of your shell session, it appears there
are more problems with your setup.
And there are problems with your approach to Go.

First, while it looks like you're following
[this guide](https://golang.org/doc/install) (and this is the right thing
to do, actually), you misread it.

What it tried to tell you is that you should create the "src"
directory (and then the "hello" directory to contain your test project)
in the so-called *workspace,* and a list of workspaces known to Go
is stored in the `GOPATH` environment variable.

As you can see from the `go env` output, Go thinks you have a single
workspace located in `C:\Users\Sitaram\Go`.

Now it worth reiterating that—contrary to many (if not most) "mainstream"
languages,—Go is not "project-based"; instead, it requires all your code
to be organized in those workspaces, and it wants to know where these
workspaces are.
By default—if you did not explicitly set the `GOPATH` environment
variable,—it assumes your single workspace is located in the directory
named "go" placed in your "home folder".
And that's what you see in the `go env` output.

Now you have two options:

- Set the `GOPATH` env. variable for your user to `C:\GOCODE`
  then start another shell—so that it "sees" that variable and allows
  the `go` tool to also see it and use).
  Run `go env` to verify `GOPATH` contains `C:\GOCODE`.

  Then follow the rest of the tutorial document:

  1. Make sure there is the "src" folder directly under the `C:\GOCODE`.
  2. Create your project folder directory under "src".
     Let's say, it will be named "hello".
  3. Under "hello", create that "hello.go" file.
  4. Now `cd C:\GOCODE\src\hello` and then `go build` — you will have
     the `hello.exe` created there.
- Don't mess with `GOPATH` and just repeat the steps 2-4 from above
  in the default workspace—`C:\Users\Sitaram\go`.

I'd go with the second variant because that inexplicable affection
of certain Windows users for polluting the `C:\` with random *personal*
data is really an anti-pattern; have your personal belongings in your home
folder! Windows has gone a long way getting that right; and almost all
Windows software is finally there—understanding that paradigm. So why deviate?

Second, please *unlearn* `go run`.
I'm not sure the Go developers actually regret implementing it,
but people do really misinterpret what this tool is for.
It's for one-off throw-away "scripts".
Real development is done using `go install` and, sometimes, `go build`.

In most cases your normal development routine you use `go install`
exclusively — as it caches the results of compilation of all the packages
your project depends on. `go build` does not do this, and `go run` does
not even preserve the result of the compilation of your project itself.
Please read [this](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/06/04/what-does-go-build-build) quick reference card for more info.

Answer (score 0):

After go get gpackage check if there is a yourproject.exe in your bin directory to compile your github package with your project.
If not, you have to do cd src/yourproject and type go install and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

Try execute the folowing command e check if corrected:

go env -w GOOS=windows